# In j, how can I define a verb locally in one scope and pass it to a defined adverb?

Tags: j

I am getting an unexpected `value error` when I use a name to pass a verb as the argument to an adverb.

The adverb (integer binary search with predicate `u` and bounds `x`):

```
   bsearch=: adverb define
r=. y NB. range
while. ~:/ 1 0 + r do.
n=. ([: -: ] - 2&|) +/r NB. next
r=. n (u n)}r
end.
{.r
)
```

Some working code:

```
   >&3 bsearch 1 11
3
   works=: monad define
r=. 1,y
>&3 bsearch r
)
   works 11
3
```

And now for the surprising behavior:

```
   breaks=: monad define
p=. >&3
r=. 1,y
p bsearch r
)
   breaks 11
|value error: p
|   r=.n(    u n)}r
```

Setting stops and debugging shows the expected name classes at `p bsearch r` (verb adverb noun).

```
   reset=: 13!:0
   reset 1
   13!:3'breaks 2'
   breaks 11
|stop: breaks
|   p bsearch r
|breaks[2]
      4!:0 ;:'p bsearch r'
3 1 0
      5!:4<'p'
      ┌─ >
── & ─┴─ 3
      13!:21''
|stop: bsearch
|   r=.y
|bsearch[0]
      5!:4<'u'
── p
```

Inside `breaks` everything is as expected.  Inside `bsearch` the verb `u` is defined in terms of a private var `p` that isn't there.  This is completely unexpected and difficult to work with for more complex use cases.

I tried a little indirection by using `([: p ])` instead of `p` but the results were similar.

Using `=:` to set `p` in `breaks` does solve the immediate problem but is an untenable solution.

One workaround might be to have a tacit definition of `bsearch` so that using it doesn't introduce a new scope.  I think that may be what I need here, but I want a more general solution and I want an understanding of why what I have doesn't work.  What I want to be able to do is define a verb in a local scope and pass it or a verb derived from it to an explicitly defined adverb or conjunction.

Thanks

Comment: FYI: `9!:14''` => `j903/j64avx2/darwin/release-b/commercial/www.jsoftware.com/2022-01-28T04:20:11/clang-13-0-0/SLEEF=1`

Comment: The quick fix is to use `p f. bsearch r`. The issue is J’s grammar passes proverbs by name, not value, and since `p` is defined *locally* in `breaks`, then `bsearch` receives literally `p` as an argument, it can’t resolve it, because the name has gone out of scope (it’s private to `breaks`). Using `p f.` forces J to pass the verb by value.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks!  That comment is a complete answer.  1) Why? => "J’s grammar passes proverbs by name" 2) Best idiomatic solution? => `f.`

Comment: Yes. Bear in mind that `f.` has at least one sharp corner: if you have a tacit verb `myverb` composed of other named tacit verbs, e.g. `myverb =: subverb0@subverb1@subverb2`, then if any of the subverbs (for the sake of argument, let’s say `subverb1`) uses `$:` (recurse / callself), then in the non-`f.` `myverb`, the `$:` will refer to `subverb1` (ie recurse only in that sub-component), whereas in `myverb f.`, `$:` refers to the *whole of `myverb`, and will receive from the top level, which is almost certainly not what you want. There are easy workarounds, but thought I’d highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use u. (and v. for a conjunction) in place of u (and v).  u. is similar to u, but it uses the environment of the caller.  If you define bsearch as follows:

```
bsearch=: adverb define
r=. y NB. range
while. ~:/ 1 0 + r do.
n=. ([: -: ] - 2&|) +/r NB. next
r=. n (u. n)} r
end.
{.r
)
```

Then it should do what you want.  See [wiki](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/udot).